# List of US Indices

Tags: data, market-data

I need to do symbology translations between two financial systems. One part of this is to identify a symbol that is an index in one system so that I can prepend a character to it when I send it to the other. The first system does not use any special formatting to indicate that a symbol is an index.

To do this I need to find a list of all US Indices so I can classify a symbol via a lookup. At minimum I need an index's symbol but I would also like to have its CUSIP and Name. Ideally it would be a data source that is updated on a regular basis that I can programmatically pull from.

**Does anyone know a good data source for US Indices?** Free is always good!

Comment: @Bob Jansen. The referenced question is very general and I don't find its answers useful in answering my question. Is there a specific answer given on that question that you though addressed my question?

Comment: Quandl would be a start as said. However I'm afraid there is no perfect answer to this question as there is no free database of all CUSIPs or indices that is known (otherwise I would hope it be in the linked question). If you're willing to pay good money your question can probably be answered but I believe you're not looking for such a service.

Answer (score 0):

I found a good lis of indices from [QUANDL](https://www.quandl.com/collections/markets/us-stock-indexes) . They have a nice list of indices which you can pull from by ticker/symbol. I am not aware they provide by CUSIP